# error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type `int' to `bool' - Unity3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, int, boolean

I got error `CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type int to bool error`.

Here's my code :

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class card2 : MonoBehaviour {

public GUISkin MenuSkin;

public int cardinpuani;
public float sekiz = 8;
public float sifir = 0;
public int onalti = 16;
public int dort = 4;
public int yirmi =20;
public int oniki = 12;
public int yirmidort = 24;
public int yirmisekiz = 28;
public bool clicked = false;

void Start () {

}

void Update () {
}

void OnGUI () {

    GUI.skin = MenuSkin;

    if(GUI.Button ( new Rect (0,Screen.height-50,100,50), "No")){
        Application.LoadLevel(4);
    }
    else if(GUI.Button ( new Rect (Screen.width-100,Screen.height-50,100,50), "Yes")){
    clicked = true;
    }
    else if(clicked=true){
        if(sifir = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("tahmin", sifir)){
            PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("tahmin", sekiz);
            Application.LoadLevel(4);
        }
    }


    /*if(sifir = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("tahmin")){
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("tahmin", sekiz);
        if(3>1){
        Application.LoadLevel(4);
        }}

        else if(dort = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("tahmin")){
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("tahmin", oniki);
        Application.LoadLevel(4);
        }
        else if(onalti = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("tahmin")){
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("tahmin", yirmidort);
        Application.LoadLevel(4);
        }
        else if(yirmi = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("tahmin")){
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt("tahmin", yirmisekiz);
            Application.LoadLevel(4);
        }*/

        //PlayerPrefs.SetInt("tahmin", sekiz);

        //Application.LoadLevel(4);


}
}
```

It's simple code but I am still getting error. I tried the commented code too but not succeeded at solving problem. Any help.

Comment: You should be using `==` for comparison in `if` statement, instead of single `=`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using the assignment operator

```
(checked = true)
```

Which is not the same as

```
(checked == true)
```

The first sets the value of `checked` to `true`, the second checks if the variable `checked` is set to `true`

Answer (score 0):

```
sifir = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("tahmin", sifir)
```

PlayerPrefs.GetFloat returns a float. You can't use a float as the condition in an if statement.

You're looking to do something like

```
sifir = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("tahmin", sifir)
if(sifir != 0)
{ 
     PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("tahmin", sekiz);
     Application.LoadLevel(4); 
}
```

You're also assigning to clicked rather than evaluating clicked in some of your if statements. That'll cause a more subtle bug than failing to compile. Your compilation however, is related to the above.